# Wants to show the html tags as a string on the rails view with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to display html tags as a string in google Map Marker click event, But it shows output as html tag convert into user controls.

Ex- my_string =  "< input type=text >Test String"

Then it will display text field and then Test String.

```
my_string =  "< input type=text >Test String"
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                  map: map
                });

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                  return function() {
                    var s = unescape(escape(my_string));
                          infowindow.setContent("<a href='/"+locations[i][4]+"/result_list' target='_blank'>"+locations[i][0]+"</a>"+"<br>"
                                          +"<b>Title : </b>"+s+"<br>"
                                          +"<b>Currency : </b>"+locations[i][6]+"<br>"
                                          +"<b>Trade Amount : </b>"+locations[i][7]+"<br>"
                                          +"<b>List Created by : </b>"+locations[i][8]+""  );

                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }



                })(marker, i));
            }
```

Comment: So you're searching for <pre/>?

Comment: We have tried it but didn't get success.

Comment: please show resulted and required HTML parts

Comment: I want to display my_string = "< input type=text >Test String" this string as a title in google map marker.

Comment: Updated post with both two cases

Comment: I have updated my post . just check it.

Comment: can you give us the working fiddle?

Comment: @Bharatsoni I dont see: two cases of HTML

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mistake when defining my_string variable. It should be

```
my_string = "<input type='text'>Test String";
```

There mustn't no space between "<" and "input".

Here is the working code that I tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatlng
          }
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title: 'Hello World!'
          });

          var contentString =  "<input type='text'>Test String";

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: contentString
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
          });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print tags, you will need to replace `<>` with the equivelent HTML Entities, `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

So, your string will become:

```
my_string =  "&lt;input type=text&gt;Test String"
```